# PHP - Filter Price Rule By Date Closest To from_date

Tags: php, magento, date, collections, filter

I am trying to have a banner display on my header directly from the price rule without having to code it each time.

I created a php file that looks like:

```
<?php

/* Gets all the Magento store rules */
require 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
//echo "test1<br>";

$todayDate = date("Y-m-d");
//echo $todayDate;
$limit = 1;

/* Get all the active Catalog Rules */
$catalogrules = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
    //    ->addFieldToFilter('sort_order', 1)       
        ->addFieldToFilter('from_date', array('lteq' => $todayDate))
        ->addFieldToFilter('to_date', array('gteq' => $todayDate))
        ->addFieldToSelect('description');
foreach ($catalogrules as $rule)
{
    //echo "catalog rule:<br>";
    echo $rule->getData('description');
    echo "<br>";
}

/* Get all active Shopping Cart Rules */
$cartrules = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
    //  ->addFieldToFilter('sort_order', 1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('from_date', array('lteq' => $todayDate))
        ->addFieldToFilter('to_date', array('gteq' => $todayDate))
        ->addFieldToSelect('description');
foreach ($cartrules as $rule)
{
    //echo "cart rule:<br>";
    echo $rule->getData('description');
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

I need to filter the code that it only takes the most recently started (from_date) rule from both the catalog rule and the shopping cart rule.

PLEASE ADVISE!!

THanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

/* Gets all the Magento store rules */
require 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
//echo "test1<br>";

$todayDate = date("Y-m-d");
//echo $todayDate;
$limit = 1;

/* Get all the active Catalog Rules */
$catalogrules = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
    //    ->addFieldToFilter('sort_order', 1)       
        ->addFieldToFilter('from_date', array(array('gteq' => $todayDate), array('null' => true)))//Make these changes
        ->addFieldToFilter('to_date', array(array('lteq' => $todayDate), array('null' => true)))//Make these changes
        ->addFieldToSelect('description');
foreach ($catalogrules as $rule)
{
    //echo "catalog rule:<br>";
    echo $rule->getData('description');
    echo "<br>";
}

/* Get all active Shopping Cart Rules */
$cartrules = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
    //  ->addFieldToFilter('sort_order', 1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('from_date', array(array('gteq' => $todayDate), array('null' => true)))//Make these changes
        ->addFieldToFilter('to_date', array(array('lteq' => $todayDate), array('null' => true)))//Make these changes
        ->addFieldToSelect('description');
foreach ($cartrules as $rule)
{
    //echo "cart rule:<br>";
    echo $rule->getData('description');
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```